# How to Iterate a list in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have class

```
public class Chat
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public List<string> location { get; set; }
    public string Browser { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Os { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is how can I iterate through a list of location when displaying in repeater as Each chat instance contain multiple locations and i want to display theses locations when binding with repeater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest a second repeater and bind it directly to this property.

```
<asp:repeater id="outer" runat="server">
...
<asp:ItemTemplate>
  <asp:repeater id="inner" runat="server" datasource="location">
    ... <!-- eval here   -->
  </asp:repeater>
</asp:ItemTemplate>
...
</asp:repeater>
```